# Fastapi async.sleep() get time spent

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, fastapi

```py
async def work():
    asyncio.sleep(3)


@router.get('')
async def test():
    time1 = monotonic()
    ...  # need to call work
    time2 = monotonic()
    return TestResponse(time=time2-time1)
```

`work` function should be called only once at the same time. i need write `test` function so if i call the endpoint several times at the same time i get responses: `time`=time that differs from the previous call by at least 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the timing, but you might want to have a look at [`asyncio.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Lock). Then you'd do something like

```py
import asyncio

work_lock = asyncio.Lock()

async def work():
    async with work_lock():
        # Do your actual work
```

That should guarantee that if two requests call your endpoint, one will await the other.

Answer (score 1):

So you need a rate limiter - limiting it to 1 call each three seconds. The asyncio construction to do that is a Semaphore

you can try this code:

```
import asyncio
import time

PARALLEL = 1
INTERVAL = 3

semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(PARALLEL)



async def work():
    with semaphore:
        start = time.time()
        try:
            # do actual I/O calls here
            ...
            result = ...
        finally:
            ellapsed = time.time() - start()
            # wait to liberate semaphore:
            await asyncio.sleep(INTERVAL - ellapsed) 

    return result

...
@router.get('')
async def test():
    time1 = monotonic()
    ...  # need to call work
    time2 = monotonic()
    return TestResponse(time=time2-time1)
```